# Enc28j60 Power issues

Tags: voltage, enc28j60

I am having a weird issue with the enc28j60 controller and atemga8. I am trying to build this circuit:

[image: http://www.pocketmagic.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/simple_atmega8_webserver.png]

I am using this schematic to power up the circuit with a 9V battery:

[image]  (all the capacitors are actually 10uF)

The enc should respond to ping but I have to plug in/plug out the battery a few times before it works. Also it seems that when I add a new battery it doesn't work at all. Only when I use a slightly older 9V battery (multimeter tells me it's 7V) it works from time to time.

Any idea why is this happening since both lm accept a wide voltage range ?

Comment: Are you using the ENC28J60 IC by itself, or are you using an Evaluation Board or Dev Kit that contains this IC?

Comment: I am using a dev kit ENC28J60 Ethernet : http://dereenigne.org/wp-content/uploads/ENC28J60-300x184.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find a datasheet on that dev kit, but I think I know what the problem is.

If you go to the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39662a.pdf) of the IC and look at Figure 2-4, it shows that you will need a level shifter to bring the 3.3V output of the SO pin up to 5V so that the microcontroller can read it.  This is true of the /INT and /WOL pins as well.

If you're lucky, then your specific microcontroller can also be run at 3.3V.  Check your datasheet.  If so, then just power it from your 3.3V rail, and there shouldn't be any problems.

If not, then there are a lot of options out there to perform the level shift.  If you need help with this, please post another question :)

Good luck!

Comment: The external components have already been added to the ENC28J60 (it's a kit bought from ebay). What you are saying makes sense but why does the communication work sometimes ? 

Since I don't have access to the 74ACT125 won't changing the voltage of the microcontroller reduce it's max operating frequency thus destroying my entire program ?

PS: The original schematic has the level shifter, but it seems it can work without it : http://www.pocketmagic.net/2012/07/atmega8-and-enc28j60-for-ethernet-support/#.U1AblBDm6X_

Comment: @romanpetrov1 I believe you're right at the edge.  The ATmega8 requires an input high voltage of at least Vcc * 0.6 = 3V.  The output characteristics of the ENC aren't specified in the preliminary datasheet, but it's common for the output high to be Vcc - 0.7V = 2.6V minimum.  These specs are known to work, although there's wiggle-room on both components.  If you're right on the edge, it could explain why it works intermittently.  And, you're right, it looks like if you go under 4.5V then you can't run faster then 8MHz.

Comment: thanks for clearing everything up for me ! I will look at a way of implementing a level shifter.